# Request basic Typescript/Javascript and RxJs code explanation

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I am learning rxjs and am having a tough time wrapping my head around these two lines of code:

```
const dispatcher = fn => (...args) => appState.next(fn(...args));
const actionX = dispatcher(data =>({type: 'X', data}));
```

At least part of why I don't understand is that it is using shorthand syntax that I am not used to yet. I have been trying to expand it out to understand exactly what is happening but haven't been able to correctly do so. For instance, actionX calls dispatcher and a function is passed as a paramater but then does't actually run until that same function is called in appState.next? There seems to be a lot of functions returning functions and it is making my head spin. Any insight would be helpful.

from this:

```
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

const inputEl = document.querySelector('input');
const activeEl = document.querySelector('#active');
const doneEl = document.querySelector('done');

const appState = new Rx.BehaviorSubject({todos: []});

appState.subscribe(console.log);

const dispatcher = fn => (...args) => appState.next(fn(...args));
const actionX = dispatcher(data =>({type: 'X', data}));

actionX('some data');
```

This code logs this:

```
>{todos: Array(0)}
>{type: "X", data: "some data"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more classic JS approach without the [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (`=>`), [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) (`...args) => {}`), and [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`appState.next(fn(...args))`) for:

```
const dispatcher = fn => (...args) => appState.next(fn(...args));
```

would be:

```
const dispatcher = function (fn) {
    return function () {
        // arguments are the parameters passed to the function
        const result = fn.apply(null, arguments);
        return appState.next(result);
    };
};
```

The point of this code seems to be wrapping your callback (`fn`) passed to `dispatcher(...)` so that the `appState` is updated with the result of the callback. This makes it easier to reuse the functionality of executing some code and setting it up as the next value in your `appState`. Without this, you would need to remember to push your value back from the callback onto your app state every time.

In other words, without using this pattern, your code above would be:

```
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

const inputEl = document.querySelector('input');
const activeEl = document.querySelector('#active');
const doneEl = document.querySelector('done');

const appState = new Rx.BehaviorSubject({todos: []});

appState.subscribe(console.log);

//const dispatcher = fn => (...args) => appState.next(fn(...args));
//const actionX = dispatcher(data => ({type: 'X', data}));

const actionX = function (data) {
    appState.next({type: 'X', data: data});
};

actionX('some data');
```

This may be useful for the case where you have a single action, but what about if you have multiple ones? You will duplicate `appState.next(...)` for each of the actions. What if the dispatching of the result of your callback is more complicated? Well, that's a lot more duplication and possibilities of errors and getting out of sync with each other. This sounds like a great use of functional programming and pulling that out into a reusable function:

```
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

const inputEl = document.querySelector('input');
const activeEl = document.querySelector('#active');
const doneEl = document.querySelector('done');

const appState = new Rx.BehaviorSubject({todos: []});

appState.subscribe(console.log);

//const dispatcher = fn => (...args) => appState.next(fn(...args));
//const actionX = dispatcher(data => ({type: 'X', data}));

const dispatcher = function (state) {
    appState.next(state);
};
// or for a shorter modern version:
// const dispatcher = state => appState.next(state);

const actionX = function (data) {
    dispatcher({type: 'X', data: data});
};

actionX('some data');
```

In functional programming, there is the concept of [higher order functions](https://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html). That link defines this as:

> A higher-order function is a function that can take another function as an argument, or that returns a function as a result.

This typically is to reduce repetition and make your application more composable, to reduce the code that needs to be written. Using this philosophy we can improve the code above even more. Instead of having to retrieve the state and pass it to the dispatcher function, we can provide a function that retrieves the state and return a function so that this code can be executed many times (since we can hold onto a reference to that returned function).

```
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

const inputEl = document.querySelector('input');
const activeEl = document.querySelector('#active');
const doneEl = document.querySelector('done');

const appState = new Rx.BehaviorSubject({todos: []});

appState.subscribe(console.log);

//const dispatcher = fn => (...args) => appState.next(fn(...args));
//const actionX = dispatcher(data => ({type: 'X', data}));

const dispatcher = function (fn) {
    return function () {
        // arguments are the parameters passed to the function
        const result = fn.apply(null, arguments);
        return appState.next(result);
    };
};

const actionX = dispatcher(function (data) {
    return {type: 'X', data: data});
});

actionX('some data');
```

Using modern JS to simplify all of that code you end up with what you had:

```
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx';

const inputEl = document.querySelector('input');
const activeEl = document.querySelector('#active');
const doneEl = document.querySelector('done');

const appState = new Rx.BehaviorSubject({todos: []});

appState.subscribe(console.log);

const dispatcher = fn => (...args) => appState.next(fn(...args));
//const dispatcher = function (fn) {
//    return function () {
//        // arguments are the parameters passed to the function
//        const result = fn.apply(null, arguments);
//        return appState.next(result);
//    };
//};

const actionX = dispatcher(data => ({type: 'X', data}));
//const actionX = dispatcher(function (data) {
//    return {type: 'X', data: data});
//});

actionX('some data');
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for taking the time. I also read all of your references and they were a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

This will be the code once you remove the short hand method structure,

```
function foo1(data){
  return {type: 'X', data}
}
function dispatcher(fn){    //fn = {type:'X', data}
  function foo2(...args){
    return appState.next(fn(...args));
  };
  return foo2;
}
const actionX = dispatcher(foo1);

actionX('something')'
```

Hope this gives you a better understanding.